# Try Data(contentsOf:) throws from iPhone widget when iPhone is locked but otherwise works

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, widget

My widget properly reads (using a call to Data) from an App Group when the phone is active, but throws when the phone is locked/inactive.

Details. A Weather Event is a 336-byte struct written to and read from a JSON file stored in an App Group. The JSON file is shared between an iPhone app and an iPhone widget.

The iPhone app creates the event. The app writes the event to the App Group from where the iPhone widget reads and displays the event's data. The widget can also update (write to) the weather event. This occurs after checking--a getTimeline(…) entry--for an updated weather forecast. The widget updates AS LONG AS the phone remains active, whether or not the app is running. All good!

However, when the screen locked, the widget fails to read the data containing the JSON information. The error occurs when trying to access the data (which occurs before any attempted forecasts). The following code simplifies my code while also failing as described.

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<WeatherEntry>) -> ()) {

    Task {
        var widgetEvent: Event = Event()
        do {
            // The "try Data" call below throws only when the iPhone is locked
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: FileManager.appEventShare) // <- Throws!
            
            let widgetEvents: [Event] = try JSONDecoder().decode([Event].self, from: data)

            if !widgetEvents.isEmpty {
                widgetEvent = widgetEvents[0]
            }
            else {
                widgetEvent.userData.name = "No Event"
            }
        } catch {
            print("Widget could not open event", error.localizedDescription)
            widgetEvent.userData.name = "Failed Decode"
        }
        
        let currentDate = Date.now
        let timelineTime = timeForFiveMinuteInterval(from: currentDate)
        
        let entries = [
            WeatherEntry(date: currentDate, event: widgetEvent),
            WeatherEntry(date: timelineTime, event: widgetEvent)
        ]
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

Thoughts on what's happening?

Comment: When you create the file in your main app do you specify a file protection option?  If so, what option do you specify? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files

Comment: Paulw11, file protection was configured as .completeFileProtection. With your prompting, I updated this to .noFileProtection. The app and widget now work under all conditions! Thank you!